# How i can draw the shadow for my uiview

Tags: ios, uiview, drawing, shadow

I have a tableview where I customized the view cells and i want to draw the shadow on them. I have already use the view's layer but if i draw the shadow by this way, my tableview is very very slow.
this is the code :

```
UIView  *foreground             = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8., 8., 305, 290.)];
foreground.tag                  = kForegroundTag;
foreground.backgroundColor      = [UIColor whiteColor];
/* Draw from here */
foreground.layer.shadowColor    = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
foreground.layer.shadowOpacity  = 0.7;
foreground.layer.shadowOffset   = CGSizeMake(0., 1.);
foreground.layer.shadowRadius   = 3.;
```

Thx you for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drawing shadows using these properties can have poor performance. You have a couple of options though:

You could set `shouldRasterize` on the layer to convert it to render the layer as a bitmap instead of redrawing (be careful: this is only useful if your view does not need to be redrawn often, and can end up being worse than the existing performance if used in the wrong scenario)

The other option is to also use the `shadowPath` property on the layer. According to the `CALayer` docs:

> Specifying an explicit path usually improves rendering performance

I would definitely use the `shadowPath` property, and depending on the nature of the view, possibly set the `shouldRasterize` flag as well

Comment: This recent answer on Quora also suggests that the `shadowPath` property is the way to go and gives an example usage: http://www.quora.com/iOS-Development/What-are-some-tricks-to-make-an-iOS-app-feel-responsive/answer/Aditya-Herlambang

Comment: THX YOU VERY VERY MUCH :D I Have 60fps now :) thx for the link